# Does firebase library check for matching appId? If an application has firebase profie for some random firebase project?

Tags: firebase, gcloud, firebase-remote-config

Let's assume we have a Firebase project A and it has Firebase profile file for appId App_A.

If another app with appId App_B decoded the info from App_A and took the Firebase profile file and tried to use it within App_B will it be able to get fetch remote config from Firebase project A?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your use case, what you are trying to achieve , and, if applicable, give some examples? Would you like to fetch data that is located in different Firebase projects from your application?

Comment: No, on the contrary, I want to make sure that this won't happen. So if another app loads the profile, it won't allow to fetch or access data from the specific Firebase project that owns the profile if the appId doesn't match the one specified in the profile of the Firebase project settings.

Comment: I think you may want to take a look at **[User Based Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security)**. You can control access to data based on user identity. Then, if you would like to build user-based and role-based access system  that keep your users' data safe **[Security Rules and Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth)** can do the trick. Let me know if it helps. You can assign permissions to project members via roles. These are called [Firebase IAM permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Setting up API Key Restrictions https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions should help with this.